# Pull Data from DB for Admin Page Display as Relates to Admin Page Class by BA Internet

Tags: plugins, customization, database, array

Why do developers make it so darn hard to use the tools they develop? Don't answer, I already know :)

Have had some success using this: https://github.com/bainternet/Admin-Page-Class
 ...to develop a plugin admin page.

BA Internet, plugin developer, offers repeater fields, where I created a set of three fields to create a list of video tutorials. Here is my code:

```
$options_panel->Title(__("Video Tutorials","apc"));  
$repeater_fields_videos[] = $options_panel->addText('re_text_field_video_title',array('name'=> __('Video Title ','apc')),true);
$repeater_fields_videos[] = $options_panel->addText('re_text_field_video_url',array('name'=> __('Video URL ','apc')),true);
$repeater_fields_videos[] = $options_panel->addTextarea('re_textarea_field_video_description',array('name'=> __('Video Description ','apc')),true);
//repeater block
$options_panel->addRepeaterBlock('re_',array('sortable' => true, 'inline' => true, 'name' => __('Add your YouTube, Vimeo, or Screencast videos.','apc'),'fields' => $repeater_fields_videos, 'desc' => __('Requires full url to video.','apc')));
```

Here is the data in my fdwp101_options field within the wp-options table

```
//What I see in fdwp101_options field in the wp-options table
s:3:"re_";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{
s:16:"re_text_field_video_title";s:32:"Video Title Here";
s:23:"re_text_field_video_url";
s:18:"http://youtube.com";
s:21:"re_textarea_field_video_description";s:98:"Video description here";}}
```

Finally, the code I use  (that does not work) to display the data on my page:

```
   $data = get_option('fdwp101_options'); //name of options group 
   echo $data['re_text_field_video_title'];
```

BA Internet offers this code to pull data, though I can't get it to work for the repeater fields data:

```
//get the data to an array
$data = get_option('demo_options'); //my field is fdwp101_options
//access each field by its id
echo $data['text_field_id'];
```

Ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you copied that "What I see in fdwp101_options field" part correctly? It looks like serialized data but I can't get it to unserialize correctly.

Comment: That was a snippit of the DB. Here is the entire field:
http://pastebin.com/UNBBwvcv

Comment: Also, here is admin-page-class.php that builds the repeater blocks: http://pastebin.com/uECE4uwL